# FireBase PhoneNumber Verification Error In Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I am implementing Firebase phoneNumber Verification in my Application. Then error Generate in my Application :

> If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth\'s canHandleNotificaton: method.

Comment: no i am follow FireBase Documentation Completely

Comment: yes I am  also ues this method

Comment: Can you show us your AppDelegate ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you might missed to add this method in your AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
        completionHandler(.noData)
        return
    }
    // This notification is not auth related, developer should handle it.
    handleNotification(notification)
}
```